# ¿Como puedo filtrar un dato en especifico de mi archivo JSON?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Soy principiante con el manejo de datos JSON, y quisiera saber como puedo cargar (actualizar) el dato de mi archivo local JSON, aplicar un filtro para cargar un registro deseado por hora. Es decir, en mi archivo JSON esta un objeto hora y su respectivo valor, por ejemplo si el dia de hoy son las 13:00 horas quisiera que cargara el dato que esta en la hora 13:00 de mi archivo JSON. Anexo una fotografia de mi archivo JSON. Estoy trabajando con HTML, JavaScript y css. ¿Como puedo filtrar este dato para que muestre los valores que deseo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías cambiar el título porque "tiempo real" da a entender que quieres leer el json constantamente a tiempo real (como un flujo de datos constante) y lo que pretendes es más bien aplicar un filtro para cargar un registro deseado por fecha/hora.

Comment: @track3r muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, ya modifique mi pregunta, como decía soy principiante en el manejo de datos JSON y tengo problemas con este filtrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a suponer que lo que tienes ahí como datos es una array de objetos, en ese caso te recomiendo:

- Obtener la hora actual con [getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getHours).
- Utilizar [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para obtener de tu array de datos solo los objetos que tengan como propiedad `hora` la hora actual.
- Utilizar [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para que puedas hacer la comparación en el filter (debido a que en tu array la hora está guardada como una string con formato: `HH:MM`)

Todo junto se vería algo así:

```js
const data = [{
    hora: "13:00",
    valores: {
      valor1: 3,
      valor2: 5
    }
  },
  {
    hora: "20:00",
    valores: {
      valor1: 33,
      valor2: 89
    }
  },
  {
    hora: "13:00",
    valores: {
      valor1: 73,
      valor2: 58
    }
  },
  {
    hora: "10:00",
    valores: {
      valor1: 13,
      valor2: 55
    }
  },
  {
    hora: "10:20",
    valores: {
      valor1: 4,
      valor2: 8
    }
  },
]

function filtrarPorHoraActual(miArray) {
  const horaActual = new Date().getHours(); //Tambien puedes usar getMinutes() si quisieras filtrar por minutos
  console.log(`Filtrando objetos que tengan la hora ${horaActual}:00`);
  return miArray.filter((dato) =>
    (dato.hora === `${horaActual}:00`))
}

console.log(filtrarPorHoraActual(data))
```

Comment: FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE! muchas gracias compañero! de verdad me salvaste! disculpa la molestia, tengo otra duda, por ejemplo si de esa horaActual, quiero conocer solo un elemento de mi array por decir, solo lo que contiene valor1 (el numero 4), ¿como podria modificarse?, perdona la molestia, de verdad soy principiante.

Comment: @Clouds556 Whoops, no leí esto antes de que hicieras tu última pregunta. En ese caso una solución sería acceder el primer elemento del array, otra solución sería en vez de filtrar recorrer el array y devolver el primer objeto que cumpla con la hora actual. Esto no me parece algo bueno debido a que si la idea de tu JSON de datos es que no se repita una hora, el método de filtrado te permite validar la integridad del mismo por medio de la cantidad de resultados que arroja... Si arrojase 2 que tienen la misma hora se podría tomar como un error de integridad de datos y corregirse.